# The average size of downward closed family of the subsets of $[n]$ is at most $n/2$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, posets

I learned that the average size in any ideal of subsets of $[n]$ is at most $n/2$, but I think the downward closed family of the subsets of $[n]$ also satisfied. I want to know how to proof it or it is wrong. A downward closed family $\mathcal{F}$ means for any $A \in \mathcal{F}, B \subseteq A$, we have $B \in \mathcal{F}$, and the ideal's definition is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(set_theory).

Comment: Didn't you ask this question already? Why did you delete it and re-ask it again using a different account?

Comment: Someone posted an irrelevant discussion under the question before, maybe I should deal with it in other ways.

Comment: Please, in the future, do not repost questions in this way. In the uncommon case that someone posts a spam answer like that again, do not worry about it, it will be dealt with soon. (Note that the offending post was being heavily downvoted and, apparently, attracted spam flags. Most likely it would get deleted in short order.)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Do you mean taking the sum of the sizes of all downsets and dividing it by the total number of downsets? Or you are looking at the maximal downsets only? Do you really mean the sum, or a sort of weghted average?

Comment: @Seva I think the question is not about the average size of downsets, but about the average size of sets inside any downset.

Comment: I think @EmilJeřábek is right about the intended meaning. (The alternative, the average size of downsets, is $2^{n-1}$ for symmetry reasons.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a pedestrian answer. If $\def\cF{\mathcal F}\cF$ is a downward closed subset of $\mathcal P([n])$, we have

$$\frac1{|\cF|}\sum_{A\in\cF}|A|=\sum_{i\in[n]}\Pr_{A\in\cF}[i\in A].$$

Now, for any $i\in[n]$,

$$\Pr_{A\in\cF}[i\in A]\le\frac12,$$

because the mapping $A\mapsto A\smallsetminus\{i\}$ provides an injection

$$\{A\in\cF:i\in A\}\to\{A\in\cF:i\notin A\}.$$

Answer (score 6):

This is true and indeed, much more can be said: if $\mathcal F$ is a downward closed family of subsets of $[n]$, then 
  $$ \frac1{|\mathcal F|}\, \sum_{F\in\mathcal F} |F| \le \frac12\, \log_2|\mathcal F|; $$
equivalently, if $A\subseteq\{0,1\}^n$ is a downset, then
  $$ \frac1{|A|}\, \sum_{a\in A} w(a) \le \frac12\, \log_2 |A|, $$
where $w(a)$ is the number of non-zero components of $a$. This is Theorem 3 of the [linked paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.05539.pdf) (see also the abstract).